# How to get rid of these weird border lines around my flutter code? (flutter in android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

[image]

i am using android studio for flutter programming but sometimes  a little red box around my code appear as you see in the  picture and i everytime have to press esc button on my keyboard ,this is very annoying , can i disable it forever?

Comment: That looks like refactor and rename selection style, enter or esc will get you out. Is it possible you press some shortcuts to get it there, default one shift+f6?

Comment: good but i wanna completely disable it not by esc or sth else

Comment: Check my answer to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make disable in place refactoring with below option:

[image]